# как мне можно сделать так, чтобы при написании switch/if, выдавало case, а не default?

Tags: java, switch

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class untitled {
    public static void main(String[] args) throwsjava.io.IOException { 
    System.out.println("Справка:");
    System.out.println("1. if");
    System.out.println("2. switch");
    System.out.print("Выберите: ");

    char choise;
    choise = (char) System.in.read();

    switch (choise) {
        case '1':
            System.out.println("Оператор if:\n");
            System.out.println("if(условие) оператор");
            System.out.println("else оператор");
            break;
        case '2':
            System.out.println("Оператор switch:\n");
            System.out.println("switch (выражение) {");
            System.out.println("case константа: ");
            System.out.println(" последовательность операторов");
            System.out.println("break;");
            System.out.println(" // ...");
            System.out.println("}");
            break;
        default:
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            String Mishin;
            Mishin = in.nextLine();
            switch (Mishin) {
                case "if":
                    System.out.println("Оператор if:\n");
                    System.out.println("if(условие) оператор");
                    System.out.println("else оператор");
                    break;
                case "switch":
                    System.out.println("Оператор switch:\n");
                    System.out.println("switch (выражение) {");
                    System.out.println("case константа: ");
                    System.out.println(" последовательность операторов");
                    System.out.println("break;");
                    System.out.println(" // ...");
                    System.out.println("}");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Запрос не найден.");
            }
    }
}
}
```

пожалуйста, доступным языком, не так давно начал изучать программирование. спасибо.

Comment: upd: при введение цифр все хорошо, я имею ввиду после ввода текстом switch/if.

Comment: А какая версия java? До 7 можно через Enum.valueOf. После — просто switch(String)

Comment: 12.0.1. 
Покажете, пожалуйста, как?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто укажите нужные case, как строки.
`Scanner.next()` читает следующий токен в строку.

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String key = s.next();
    switch (key) {
      case "if": 
      case "1":
        System.out.println("if about");
        break;
      case "switch":
      case "2":
        System.out.println("switch about");
        break;
      default:
        System.out.println("Запрос не найден.");
    }
```